# Banshee 2.9 install in ubuntu

Tags: banshee

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 amd64, and i want to install the latest version of banshee which is 2.9.how?

What should i do?

i try apt-get update and then apt-get dist-upgrade but still the same version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Banshee Official PPA, update the local repository index and install the banshee package and then install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install banshee
```

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Didn't work for me.